# Creating a QuickSort for an Array of names

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

So I am working on a project for my class and I am currently stuck on creating a QuickSort class to sort an Array of 1000 names. I have a template I am using from a previous Lab we did in class which we are supposed to base it off of; but in the lab we used an array of Integers and I am struggling with how to convert it so it will work with Strings; names. Thanks for your help or any suggestions, the code is below.

Updated post; So I made my comparison in my Name class

```
 public int compareTo(Object other) {
        int result;
        if (name.equals(((Name) other).name))
            result = name.compareTo(((Name) other).name);
        else
            result = name.compareTo(((Name) other).name);

        return result;
    }
```

And I've tried to re-work my QuickSort..I'm struggling with the swap method.

```
    private ArrayList<Name> data;

public QuickSort(ArrayList<Name> initialValue){

    data=initialValue;
}

public void sort(ArrayList<Name> namelist, int i, int j){

    sort(0, data.size()-1);
}

public void sort(int from, int to){

    if (from >= to)
        return;
    int p = partition(from, to);
    sort(from, p);
    sort( p + 1, to);
}

private int partition(int from, int to){

    Name pivot = data.get(from);
    int i = from - 1;
    int j = to + 1;

    while(i<j){

        i++; while(data.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0) i++;
        j--; while(data.get(j).compareTo(pivot) < 0) j--;
        if(i<j) swap(i,j);

    }

    return j;
}

private void swap (int i, int j){

    Name temp = data.get(i);
    data.equals(i) = data.get(j);
    data = temp;

}
```

particularly  the "data.equals(i) = data.get(j) line and the data = temp; I am sure i'm doing something stupid and easy.

update;

```
private void swap (int i, int j){

    Name temp = data.get(i);
    data.get(j).equals(data.get(i));
    data.get(j).equals(temp);

}
```

possibly?

Comment: testing for equality between two strings is done with the equals method, not with == as you did in your while loop's body in NameTester at places like newCommand == "N"...should be newCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("n")

Comment: while(data[i] < pivot) --> while (data.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0) compareTo returns an int. See the link to the API Doc.

Comment: Thanks I'm currently looking at the API Doc link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the code that will solve the problem would be easy but won't help you to learn the meaning of QuickSort (or another sorting algorithm).

The heart of the QuickSort is exchanging the elements here:

```
while(i<j){
    i++; while(data[i] < pivot) i++;
    j--; while(data[j] > pivot) j--;
    if(i<j) swap(i,j);
}
```

As you can see, you're comparing the elements of the `data` array against the `pivot` variable. Since they're `int`s, you can easily compare them using `<`. Now, you have to do something similar but for `String`s. Thankfully, `String`s can be compared using `String#compareTo` method. I'll let you this implementation for `String` (otherwise I will present the homework assignment as mine =P).

For a more generic solution to the problem, you have two options:

- Making your class implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, so you will have a `compareTo` method. A basic 
  sample implementation:

  ```
  public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {
      @Override
      public int compareTo(Name name) {
          return ... //comparison logic...
      }
  }
  ```

  Using it in your QuickSort

  ```
  pivot.compareTo(...);
  ```
- Using an instance of [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface. You will use `Comparator#compare` for this. A basic sample implementation:

  ```
  public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Name> {
      @Override
      public int compare(Name name1, Name name2) {
          return ... //comparison logic...
      }
  }
  ```

  Using it in your QuickSort

  ```
  NameComparator nameComparator = new NameComparator();
  nameComparator.compare(..., ...);
  ```

Comment: so would I need a compareTo method that I need to write in my Name class?

Comment: @user2514769 that's a possibility. To make it easier, just make your `Name` class implements the `Comparable` interface that forces you to implement the `compareTo` method.

Comment: @user2514769 answer updated. Note that I don't provide a real logic for the comparison because, again, that will mean doing the assignment for you.

Comment: Ha thats fine; don't mind doing the assignment just trying to wrap my head around it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator: Comparator.compare(o1, o2) returns -1, 0 or 1 if the objects are less, equal or greater.

Strings in java are actually comparable, some sort of a companion interface:

```
 int compareTo(T other);
```

API Do: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: Our prof wants us to create a QuickSort class to do it; we can't use Comparator to my knowledge. Sort of an exercise on building the method from the ground up.

Comment: Comparator is just the abstraction to compare objects. An object can be compared by an external comparator or the objects can compare them self which is the case for strings. I'm sure you can use this otherwise you would have to implement string comparison which has nothing to do with quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in string comparison is by equals method:

```
data.get(j) == pivot => data.get(j).equals(pivot)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set a String value to compare it to something. So by setting the pivot value to compare it to itself it will return zero. Since it is unlikely that all Strings will equal your pivot value then anything compared to pivot value will be returned as -1 OR 1. By doing this your if statement will determine which way the swap value is sent( Higher OR Lower) then your pivot value.

```
    ObjectQuickSorter sortStrings = new ObjectQuickSorter();
    sortStrings.sort(arrayHere);

    class ObjectQuickSorter{

    void sort(String[] array){
        doQuickSort(array, 0, array.length -1);
    }

    private static void doQuickSort(String[] array,int start, int end){
        int pivotPoint;

        if(start < end){
            pivotPoint = partition(array, start, end);

            doQuickSort(array, start, pivotPoint -1);

            doQuickSort(array, pivotPoint + 1, end);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(String[] array, int start, int end){
        String pivotValue;
        int endOfLeftList;
        int mid = (start + end)/2;

        swap(array, start, mid);

        pivotValue = array[start];

        endOfLeftList = start;

        for(int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++){
            // trying to compare pivot = string value to array[scan] position value
            // doing this by setting pivot value compare to itself to return 0
            // then also comparing pivot value to array[scan] to return -1, 0, 1
            // if return is 0 or 1 then it ignores it
            if(  array[scan].compareTo(pivotValue) < array[start].compareTo(pivotValue)){
                endOfLeftList++;
                swap(array, endOfLeftList,scan);
            }
        }

        swap(array, start, endOfLeftList);

        return endOfLeftList;
    }

    private static void swap(String[] array, int a, int b){
        String temp;

        temp = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe add some text to it?